# How do I run two NEMA 17 stepper motor from a 5v 3a powerbank?

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, gpio, stepper-driver, powerbanks

The motors are 2 phased 4 wires 3.3v @ 1.5a, and I need them to run from a powerbank, how do I control and provide the motors with power? Which drivers are needed? They will be controlled by a Raspberry Pi. I have some female USB-C 3.1 connectors lying around, can I use these to connect to the GPIO board from the powerbank?